# How to return an empty array instead of null array?

Tags: arrays, class, java-7, static-methods

I'm trying to return an array but got 'null pointer exception'. I suppose it's because my method returns an array with elements that are `null`. How to properly return an empty array?

In main class `main` method:

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int s = 0;
    Project arr[] = new Project[3];
    for(int i = 0; i!=3; i++){

        Project var = Project.getProject(arr, "Programming");
        if (var == null){
            var = new Project();
            var.setName("Programming");
            arr[s]= var;
            s=s+1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Method in separate class:

```
static Project getProject(Project[] a, String n) {
    for (int i = 0; i != a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].getName().equals(n))
            return a[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Project.getProject(Project.java:12)
at Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

Comment: There is no method *returning* an array in your code. As long as there is no method returning an array, it’s impossible to return an empty array. As far as your intent is guessable, you have a variable `s` which conceptionally represents the size of the list, i.e. the number of non-`null` entries in your array. So you should pass that number to your `getProject` method as another parameter and let that method iterate to `s` only instead of `array.length`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is because of not understanding what the array *elements* are initialized to. This has to do nothing with the array itself being `null`, but it has to do with the array element(s) being `null`.

Look at the line `Project arr[] = new Project[3];` in your `main` method. When this line is *interpreted* by Java, an array of length `3` comes into existence. The `identifier` called `arr` now has a `non-null` value. This identifier (or reference) now points to a memory where the array elements are stored. But those array elements themselves are initialized to what value?

Yes, `null`.

Thus, at this point in time, `arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = null`.

Now, at the line `Project var = Project.getProject(arr, "Programming");`, you are sending this reference `arr` to a method `getProject` which tries to iterate through that array. When `i is 0`, `a[i] = a[0] = null`! On this `null` reference, your code ends up calling `getName()` and that's the reason you get a `NullPointerException`.

Your intentions seem to be straightforward, but somehow because of some complex implementation, this kind of code has been created. You should just initialize the array instances simply. There are many, many good ways of doing this in Java, but here is where one could start:

```
    String[] names = new String[]{"Programming", "Database", "Theory"};
    Project arr[] = new Project[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = new Project();
        arr[i].setName(names[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the array (`array.length`) before getting or assigning something